# Propagation.REQUIRED: not rolled out the transaction

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-transactions

I am using spring boot + jpa.

I defined my dao layer like below.

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void save(Employee emp) {
        entityManager.persist(emp);
    }

    .....
    .....
}
```

I am calling 'saveEmployees' method, which in turn call throwException method.

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo() {
    return (args) -> {
        try {
            saveEmployees();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        empDao.all().forEach(System.out::println);

    };
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void thowException() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Throwing run time exception");
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void saveEmployees() {
    Employee emp1 = new Employee();
    emp1.setFirstName("Sandeep");
    emp1.setLastName("Maj");

    Employee emp2 = new Employee();
    emp2.setFirstName("Swaroop");
    emp2.setLastName("kdp");

    empDao.save(emp1);
    empDao.save(emp2);

    thowException();

}
```

But, When I call saveEmployees method, I am expecting the transaction that saves emp1 and emp2 should rolled back, but it is not happening...Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Probably demo() already is @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) by other means. In that case the search would be done inside the transaction not rolledback yet.

Comment: Are you sure, your methods are running in the transaction boundary? If you are calling methods of the same bean, it doesn't go through proxy. In that case you can create a separate class with saveEmployees() and throwException() methods and add that bean in the configuration.